# Como cambiar una imagen por codigo en XAMARIN

Tags: c#, imagen, xamarin

Necesito cambiar la imagen de un boton es es el xml:

```
<Image  WidthRequest="64" 
        HeightRequest="64"
        Source="{Binding Path=ImageProperty}"
        x:Name="btnGeneralPlayer"
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
         Margin="18,0,5,10"
        Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.RowSpan="2" 
       Grid.Row="0">
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, por favor revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu publicación sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Favor de ayudar en vez de criticar....

Comment: He buscado una respuesta clara incluso en la version en ingles de este foro y no hay nada claro la pregunta esta muy explicita dice cambiar una imagen por codigo en xamarin y pongo el ejemplo que uso del xaml no se que mas quieres??

Comment: En ningún momento te estoy criticando, te estoy dando un consejo para que mejores tus aportes siguiendo los lineamientos del sitio, no me lo estoy inventando yo, existen y deberían usarse. Nadie te obliga a tomarlo en cuenta

Comment: Esto de claro no tiene nada. Mencionas Xamarin, pero no especificas si es Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar las imágenes dinámicas de la siguiente manera:

Código Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageProfile.Source, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Para cambiarla debes hacer lo siguiente en tu ViewModel:

```
    private Image _imageProfile;

    public Image ImageProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageProfile;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_imageProfile != value)
            {
                _imageProfile = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageProfile)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Puedes cambiar la imagen desde archivos en la App:

```
    ImageProfile.Source = "avatar.png";
    ImageProfile.Source = "profile.png";
```

Desde una URL:

```
    ImageProfile.Source = new UriImageSource
    {
        CachingEnabled = false,
        Uri = new Uri(App.PictureURL)
    };
```

O desde un Stream:

```
ImageProfile.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(BytesImage));
```

Si desconoces el patrón MVVM da clic [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).

Answer (score -3):

Usa esto dentro de un metodo y llamalo desde la parte donde quieres hacer la modificacion de la imagen:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                    Task.Delay(100).Wait(); // Retardo
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        /*modificaciones a elementos UI*/
                    });

            });
```

PD: Tmb me caen mal las personas como jheyman  :V

Comment: Aunque la respuesta puede que ayude, es muy pobre y necesita más explicación. Por favor, editala para añadir una explicación de lo que haces. En cuanto a Jheyman, hace lo que debe, ya que este sitio funciona así y por tanto, igual que él, te recomiendo que repases las normas.

Comment: pueden borrar la pregunta, si se ponene asi mejor borrenla